# I need to upload a file testing a web application - how do I this with python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is the form that I am trying to test automated. Once I click the "upload" button I get stuck at the window that pops up where I can select a file.

**python/selenium**

> driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-content-clientarea-wrapper"]/div[1]/div/section/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/button').click()
>   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").clear()
>   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("/test.pdf")
>   driver.find_element_by_name("stepSubmit").click()

**web form**

```
<div class="white-block verify_doc" style="padding-top:40px">
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-submitted"
          name="filesUpload" style="">
        <div class="section_block col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="form-group required">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="consent-for-verification">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="consent-for-verification" id="consent-for-verification"
                               required="" ng-model="consentVerification" class="ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched"
                               style="">text
                        <show-more>
                            <a class="cursor-pointer" ng-hide="open" ng-click="open=true">text</a>
                            <a class="cursor-pointer ng-hide" ng-show="open" ng-click="open=false">text</a>
                            <div ng-show="open" ng-transclude="" class="ng-hide">
                                <div translate="borrower-loan.verifyDoc.consentVerificationFull">text</div>
                            </div>
                        </show-more>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="filesUpload.consent-for-verification.$error.required &amp;&amp; filesUpload.consent-for-verification.$dirty"
                     class="ng-hide">error</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" disabled-block="false">
                <div class="block-mask" style="min-height: 224px;"></div>
                <div>
                    <br>
                    <p translate="">text</p>
                    <p translate="borrower-loan.verifyDoc.employment.employed">text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 verify-lable-block verification-label-wrap help-label-span">
                    <label class="control-label" for="verify-income">
                        <span>text</span>
                        <help-popover translate-key="'borrower-loan.verifyDoc.incomeHint'">
                            <button type="button" class="col-xs-1 info badge btn btn-default" bs-popover=""
                                    data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" data-delay="5" data-content="text">?</button>
                        </help-popover>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
                    <div xl-file-uploaded="" files="data.files" remove-file="removeFile">
                        <div class="files form-control">
                            <!-- ngRepeat: file in files -->
                                                                    <span class="file" ng-repeat="file in files" style="">Screenshot 2015-11-04 17.34.56.png
                                                                        <!-- ngIf: removeFile -->
                                                                        <a href="" ng-if="removeFile" ng-click="removeFile(file.uuid)">x</a>
                                                                        <!-- end ngIf: removeFile -->
                                                                    </span>
                            <!-- end ngRepeat: file in files -->
                                                                    <span class="file" ng-repeat="file in files" style="">Screenshot 2015-11-05 10.38.47.png
                                                                        <!-- ngIf: removeFile -->
                                                                        <a href="" ng-if="removeFile" ng-click="removeFile(file.uuid)">x</a>
                                                                        <!-- end ngIf: removeFile -->
                                                                    </span>
                            <!-- end ngRepeat: file in files -->
                                                                    <span class="file" ng-repeat="file in files">Screenshot 2015-11-05 10.38.47.png
                                                                        <!-- ngIf: removeFile -->
                                                                        <a href="" ng-if="removeFile" ng-click="removeFile(file.uuid)">x</a>
                                                                        <!-- end ngIf: removeFile -->
                                                                    </span>
                            <!-- end ngRepeat: file in files -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2" xl-upload-controls=""
                     type="'userIncome'" add-files="addFiles($files)">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 icon-sync-2 icon-blue-large ng-hide" ng-click="removeFiles(type)"
                         ng-show="data[type].length"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 icon-check-circle-1 icon-yellow-large ng-hide"
                         ng-show="data.uploadSuccess[type]"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 verification-label-wrap"
                         ng-hide="data.uploadSuccess[type] || data[type].length">
                        <button class="blue-opposite btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-multiple="true"
                                ng-file-select="" ng-file-change="addFiles({'$files': $files, 'type': type});"
                                style="overflow: hidden;">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ngIf: data.incomeMissing -->
                <!-- ngIf: data.fileInvalid -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 x-center form-topic" translate="">text
                <span>PDF, JPEG, PNG</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 x-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="stepSubmit" ng-click="nextStep()"
                            ng-disabled="saving || data.uploading || !consentVerification" type="button">text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, are you sure your xpath is correct? `//input[@type='file']` does not seem to be correct. Instead try using `//input[@id='consent-for-verification']`.